What's preventing The Silence from correcting the order to kill their kind?
Doctor Who tricked The Silence into giving an order to kill them that compels humans to do just that, but what's stopping them from telling people trying to kill them to not kill them?

Nothing, presumably, but it's going to get tiresome having humans constantly trying to shoot you every time they see you. Plus every time they see the recording of the moon landing, they'll inexplicably start trying to kill you again.

https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/Square_One_(Gallifrey_audio_story)

Personally I'd assume the efforts of the Silence stopped after the Lake Silencio incident anyway.  If any of that faction survived time breaking down (and we never saw the Kovarian faction again after that) they would have either assumed they were successful killing him or baffled as to how the Doctor could both be dead and make it to Trenzalore.

Because that command to waste any Silence they find is embedded in not only the broadcast on the day but remains in every subsequent recording of that broadcast, they'd have to sneak around every human and edit the kill order out of every copy ever made.
Even if they manage to get the command out of the heads of any number of humans it'll just get put back in the next time someone feels like referencing the moon landing.

Honestly editing the video seems relatively trivial.  Maybe on the order of 1000 copies assuming every affiliate channel on the planet made one and likely closer to 10 for major studio archives.

They can try, but it will be difficult, and won't help enough to keep them safe
The moon broadcast reached an extraordinary number of people, all at once. Therefore, during every subsequent encounter with any humans, every human will immediately try to kill the Silent. Since it takes time to command a human to disregard previous commands, and opportunities to reach a vast audience are rare*, the Silents are out of luck.
Since the Silents have had up to this point, complete control of humanity, it's possible (or even likely) that they don't know how to use human technology well enough to hijack a broadcast directly - why would they learn that skill since up to 1969, they could far more easily order a human to do whatever they want rather than do it themselves.
*Image a Silent trying to hijack a Superbowl, World Cup, or Olympics broadcast - any human onsite will be attacking the Silent before the broadcast can reach the intended large audience.

What's a Superbowl - isn't that something that only a subset of people in one particular country are interested in? Hardly on par with the recording of the first man on the moon, nor even the World Cup or Olympics.

@Randal'Thor - In several of the Big Finish audiobooks the Silence try to co-opt various broadcasts in order to command humanity to stop attacking them.

You don't actually need to be on site to highjack a broadcast, you can sneak hack into the broadcast remotely

Sorry - a "Super Bowl" (aka a "Superb Owl") is a popular local attraction in some of the provinces

@Dave: It's not clear how much technical expertise the Silence have - they seem to do everything via humans, which is going to be a problem for them in the post-Apollo era. In fact, I'll update my answer to mention that.
